# Web tab and iframe not showing website

Tags: visualforce, force.com

I tried to show client website with both iframe and web tab but both method are not working.Is it due to secruity against clickjacking.

If not can you help me please. Here are the Error screen

[image: Error with web tab implementation]

[image: Error with iframe implementation]

Comment: Do you have root access to the client website server ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
>      X-Frame-Options: mydomain.salesforce.com
> ```

**Observation:**

If you are able to open the URL in separate window but not on iframe then the issue is clearly *as you mentioned* protection against **clickjacking**.

**Fix:**

- If you have access to web/application server of the client website (I mean the shell or root access) then its really straightforward.
- You need to set the http header `X-Frame-Options: *`, which means you are opening up to **all the domain origin** to render your URL inside an iframe.
- If you really know the parent URL name and if its always the same I would recommend using `X-Frame-Options: mydomain.salesforce.com`, which is safer

possible options are:

#### DENY

- The page cannot be displayed in a frame, regardless of the site attempting to do so.

#### SAMEORIGIN

- The page can only be displayed in a frame on the same origin as the page itself.

#### ALLOW-FROM uri

- The page can only be displayed in a frame on the specified origin.

**Reference:**

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/X-Frame-Options

Comment: I Don't have the root access but from your answer i get it that if i request the client for root and apply it to my code then i will be able to show the website in iframe and web tab.